# How to change the Piniew OTP Field Design From Boxes To Simple Line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

This is the code I got online for OTP Self Verification:

```
 <com.chaos.view.PinView
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/otp_view"
        app:itemCount="6"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:itemBackground="@color/GrayColorOTP"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        app:itemHeight="@dimen/_40sdp"
        app:itemWidth="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        app:viewType="line"
        app:lineColor="@color/GrayColorOTP"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493" 
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_VerifyNumber"/>
```

This code show a box in the pinview.
Now I want to convert the boxes design to simple lines. Please suggest me the changes required in the above code.

Comment: Add library code in your project and then customize if you want to use this particular library for your project, else you can switch to another library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library instead 
    "implementation 'me.philio:pinentryview:1.0.6'"  refer from https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView

```
        `<me.philio.pinentry.PinEntryView
        android:id="@+id/pin_entry_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:accentType="none"
        app:digitTextSize="6sp"
        app:digitSpacing="10dp"
        app:numDigits="4"
        app:digitElevation="2dp"
        app:mask=""
        app:accentWidth="10dp"
        app:digitTextColor="#0013e9"
        app:pinAccentColor="#0013e9"
        app:pinInputType="number" />`
```